# JBoss Server started, but deployment shows error

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to start JBoss server through eclipse and i want access postgres database. It shows the welcome page index.html. But deployment shows no deployed services. I have added all the jars.
Version Details: Eclipse Juno, JBoss 7.1, Java 7

This is the error stack : [Error Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iluid.png)

This is the console log:

```
17:23:17,342 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:23:17,608 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:23:17,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
17:23:18,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:23:18,489 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
17:23:18,498 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
17:23:18,504 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
17:23:18,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
17:23:18,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
17:23:18,616 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
17:23:18,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:23:18,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
17:23:18,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
17:23:18,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:23:18,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
17:23:18,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
17:23:18,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
17:23:18,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:23:19,200 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
17:23:19,278 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
17:23:19,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
17:23:19,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
17:23:19,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:23:19,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\WorkspaceWeb_New\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
17:23:19,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found JbossRest.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called JbossRest.war.dodeploy
17:23:19,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "JbossRest.war"
17:23:19,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.2)
17:23:20,047 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /JbossRest
17:23:20,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 2974ms - Started 173 of 246 services (72 services are passive or on-demand)
17:23:20,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "JbossRest.war"
```

Can anybody help me. I'm in a hurry. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post error stack trace?

Comment: Can you post error ?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question with the error

Comment: I don't see any errors. Just a successful deploy of `JbossRest.war`.

Comment: But when i try to open it in localhost:8080 it shows error http 404, Requested resource not available.

Comment: @Swathy clear the cache on the browser and check. I do not see any error with the logs provided. You may need to try 1. Check if the war is in deployment folder configured on the scanner 2. Go to deployments on the admin console and check the status 3. Go to data/context and see if there is any entry for that war.